# What is the first current object in compareTo() method in JAVA comparable interface?

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

What is the working style of `compareTo(Object o)` method. How the first object of a set is compared? Every time when an object is created the constructor is called and the values are assigned with `this` for class variables and the same class variables are compared with Object `o`, but, what is `o` in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by set? `java.util.Set`? This is an interface an does not extend `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: Set I meant is any collection implementation by implementing Set interface. I found there are two interfaces Comparable and Comparator to sort the objects inside a collection, so just wanted to know what the first object is compared to. @Würgspaß