# How does this.method variable differs from object.method when comparing two objects with Comparable interface?

Tags: java, data-structures, comparable, compareto

Taking for example these code snippets:

```
 public int compareTo(DSA_Student C){
    if (this.getName().compareTo(C.getName())<0) return -1;
    else
        if (this.getName().compareTo(C.getName())>0) return 1;
        else return (new Integer(this.getStudentId()).compareTo(new Integer(C.getStudentId())));
}
```

In the main class:

```
SortedSet <DSA_Student> S1=new TreeSet<DSA_Student>();
    DSA_Student a=new DSA_Student("A",10);
    DSA_Student b=new DSA_Student("F",40);
    DSA_Student c=new DSA_Student("B",49);
    DSA_Student d=new DSA_Student("E",45);
    DSA_Student e=new DSA_Student("D",30);
    DSA_Student f=new DSA_Student("C",45);
    DSA_Student g=new DSA_Student("B",45);

    S1.add(a);
    S1.add(b);
    S1.add(c);
    S1.add(d);
    S1.add(e);
    S1.add(f);
    S1.add(g);
```

I want to know what this.getName() and C.getName() are referring to and how does the compiler know that they are two different objects and thereby do the comparison?

Comment: The compiler **doesn't** know that they refer to two different objects, just that they refer to the `this` object and to whatever object is referred to by the C (badly named) parameter. They could in fact be one and the same object, or C may in fact be a null reference.

Comment: `this` is the instance on which `compareTo` is called; `C` is the parameter it was passed. For example in `a.compareTo(b)` `this` is `a`, `C` is `b`.

Comment: Note: `compareTo` is not called at all, because you're passing in a `Comparator`, unless that `Comparator` happens to call `compareTo`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase my question well. What I intended to ask is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752908/what-is-the-first-current-object-in-compareto-method-in-java-comparable-interf?rq=1

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, I mistakenly used Comparator. I have edited that part in the codes

Answer (score 2):

`this.getName()` means getting name of its own object

`C.getName()` means getting name of object c

`compareTo` method used for comparing itself to other object passed

`Comparable` interface provides method declaration to comparing its own object to other object passed in its `compareTo` method.

**Update :**

As you have asked that working mechanism of `TreeSet` in using Comparable `compareTo` method, it's better to look into source code of `TreeMap` as `TreeSet` internally use `TreeMap` put method when adding object. As TreeSet keep its element in sorted order, it sorts whenever there is addition of element in `TreeSet`. You can have [source code of TreeMap put method here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.put%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29). I've taken out only relevant implementation of `put` method which is related for using `Comparable` `compareTo`  method :

```
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            // This is where it takes your custom comparable object
            Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key; // 
            do {
                parent = t;
                // k as current object compareTo other object as 
                // t has been taken as root which changes 
                //its position based on comparsion
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key); 
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
```

As I am not Java expert, I would be happy to see any comment on my update to make sure that information is correct.

Comment: I got this, but don't `this.getName()` and `C.getName()` both point to the objects being added to TreeSet? How does the compiler know `    DSA_Student a=new DSA_Student("A",10);` or
    `DSA_Student b=new DSA_Student("F",40);` refers to `this.getName()` or `C.getName()`?

Comment: @Diksha : I've updated my post to answer your query in comment.